# When I move files from the desktop, windows automatically locks them. How can I stop this?

Tags: windows, permissions, desktop

Just a random windows annoyance... when I move a file from one directory to another it works as expected. When I move files from the desktop, apparently that's Special™ and windows throws a little lock icon on it, and it's no longer accessible by Everyone.

I'm sure this is for the security health of my PC and there's some very sensible reason for it but honestly I just want to disable the behavior so I don't have to keep manually changing permissions. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Desktop is tied to a specific user account, since W7 user accounts are protected it does this, I suppose you could add everyone to the security settings of the desktop folder for that user, but I don't recommend this.

Comment: That appears to have done the trick. I'm gonna be a wild gambler and keep this setting... The files had "everyone" permissions before moving to the desktop anyway. Hope there aren't any funky unforeseen consequences.

Comment: Could be security implications, not sure. MS probably does this to cut down on malware infections.

Comment: Granting "everyone" rights is not a good choice. There is one exception: This pc you are speaking of is completely isolated and has no connections anywhere. Which version of Windows do you use? I tried it myself and it does not happen (using Windows 7).

Comment: On the one hand I'm probably being dumb to make this change. I once changed my entire C: drive to "Everyone" and it caused a disaster. On the other hand I'm just sick of dealing with the lock file issue. I'm on win7 64 bit. To recreate the issue, just move any file that currently has, say, everyone permissions on it to the desktop. Then move (or cut/paste) from the desktop and to any other folder. It will lose "everyone" permissions and show a lock icon. If it matters I'm moving from the actual desktop, not via explorer C:\users\username\desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desktop is tied to a specific user account, since W7 user accounts are protected it does this, I suppose you could add everyone to the security settings of the desktop folder for that user, but I don't recommend this.